# Get everything after a keyword into a variable with grep

Tags: awk, grep

I have a curl response that returns a bunch of data, but has this in the middle:

```
Document-Disposition:qwe.ftg filename=the_document_is_201945098.zip
.
.
.
```

There are lines before and after.

In a variable, I want to be able to store `the_document_is_201945098.zip`.

I've tried using

```
grep -oP "filename=.*"
```

but this returns `filename=the_document_is_201945098.zip` onto the screen.

Comment: Does this `...` in your sample means multiple lines with new lines in your curl response?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Fortunately your `grep` supports `-P` option with which you can enjoy `Perl`'s lookaround assertion in regex.
Please try:

```
var=$(grep -oP '(?<=filename=).*' text.txt)
```

which brings you

```
the_document_is_201945098.zip
```

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 3):

In `awk` it will be simple

```
var=$(awk -F'=' '{print $2}' Input_file)
```

Since OP has put dots and didn't show complete data so trying to give more generic solution now. Here I am considering that after zip you have space so regex will match from filename to till next space you could correct me if this is not the case here.

```
var=$(awk 'match($0,/filename[^ ]*/){print substr($0,RSTART+8,RLENGTH-8)}' Input_file)
```

In case you have your curl response in a variable then use like `echo "$your_var" | awk code shown above`

Answer (score 0):

what i would do and this is under bash would be as follows.

```
variable=$(grep -m1 -o "filename=[^\ ]*" file.txt| sed 's/filename=//')
```

but again an answer isn't a solution, so let me explain.

this answer would clearly only work if there is one filename=document.zip match in the file.  if there is more than one, you could process the output of

```
grep -o "filename=[^\ ]*" | sed 's/filename=//'
```

with either a for loop, xargs, gawk or the like.

the character set [^\ ] is included for what i have always used something like this for as you would typically want everything after filename= and if there is text after the declaration you would want it to stop at the first space.  [^\ ]* mean every character that isnt a space. For sanity you could also make it [^\s]* for any whitespace which includes any space,tab,or newline.

the inclusion of

```
sed 's/filename=//'
```

just removes the part you needed for the match but dont want for the variable.

the inclusion of the $() makes the output of a command to be taken literally as a command substitution.  This command substitution is important in bash scripting as it allows you to take the output of a command or set of piped commands and use it as input in another command, which is what i have done with variable=$(command);

Answer (score 0):

This should do:

```
var=$(awk -F= '/filename=/ {print $NF}' input)
echo $var
the_document_is_201945098.zip
```

It splits the line by `=` and if it contains `filename`, print the last part.